# How do I remove the 802.1X settings in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, network, ethernet, 802.1x

I made a stupid 802.1X settings file some time ago to test some things. Now I am unable to remove it, even though I think I have deleted the file.

The picture below shows the 802.1X profile to the bottom right. How do I delete this profile? I've tried removing the ethernet with the minus sign in the left menu, but once I try to make a new ethernet profile, that 802.1X setting shows up as the standard.

[image]

Here is the picture of the 802.1X settings: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 802.1X configuration is protected with `Keychain`.

To remove it, 
select a network configuration which isn't using your 802.1X setting.

Then open `Keychain Access` (within `Applications/Utilities`).

Unlock it. Select the `login` keychains, and search for `labsenteret_peap`
which should be of kind `802.1X Password`.

Select it, remove it.

Quit `Keychain Access`.

Modify your network configuration.

And to help you manage these network configuration in the future,
give it a name better than `Location (9/13/12 9:48AM)`.
For example:
`lab. connection / Ethernet`

Comment: Cannot test this due, but accepting until sb comes up with something better. Thanks. :)

Comment: Why can't you do it? Please, don't vote for my answer as long as no one tested it with Mountain Lion. I can't because I dont use Mountain Lion anymore.

Answer (score 16):

Try `System Preferences > Profiles`. It listed my 802.1X profiles and I was able to remove them from there.

Alternatively, you can manually edit configuration files in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration` (see [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3317298)) - `grep` the files located there for the name of your profile.

(Using OS X Mavericks)

[image]
 (Profiles is located in the second row from the bottom)

Comment: Where did you get `System Preferences > Profiles`? I don't see it on Mavericks & Yosemite.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: The `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration` solution works in macOS Sierra as well. The file in question was `com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist` in my case. Emptying the file (after a backup) and restarting macOS did the job.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted. Manually editing Keychain requires a certain level of understanding as executing commands verbatim without understanding their repercussions can have serious consequences. Built-in setting options are much safer choice, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the dropdown, you can choose **edit**, there you can create a new **location**. In the new location, all settings should be on default, so your 802.1X setting shouldn't be there anymore.

Comment: If you open the dropdown, you can choose "edit", there you can create a new "location". In the new "location", all settings should be on default, so your 802.1X setting shouldn't be there anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and followed the advice to grep `eduroam` in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`.
The file I had to modify was `com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist`. In this file you can actually see, the migrated profiles.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing when you click the minus sign is disabling the ethernet port completely.  Instead, I think you want to remove an 802.1X configuration.

If you click the `Advanced...` button, a sheet will display with various tabs across the top.  One of those is **802.1X**

On the left side of the 802.1X display, you can add or delete profiles.

[image: Screenshot of 10.6 Network settings]
This screenshot is from 10.6.8; but, the principle is the same for 10.8

Comment: I added a picture to show what it looks like in 10.8

Comment: Oh... looks like I spoke too soon.  I don't know where the profile's minus sign went to in 10.8   What happens if you control-click (right-click) the profile in your list?

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: You might try this: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11323   It seems Apple has moved the configuration out of the Networks pane and into the Profiles pane?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat please make a screenshot with Command-Shift-4, release the keys, then press the spacebar and click the window. This hurts my eyes! [in detail](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/100158/55028)

Comment: Please keep this answer as it is probably valid for < 10.7, but if anyone knows the answer for 10.8 please reply. I suspect one needs to use the command line.

Answer (score -2):

I just Restarted my Laptop, and it was back to normal again.